# Angular remember the latest input data in searching fields and search result

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

I wanna store the latest input data that users fill out the search form either the search result, in order when users shift to another page and they back the data stored still there. The first thing come up into my mind is save it into `localStorage`. I'm wondering have any other way to archive this?

Comment: https://medium.com/@gerasimov.pk/how-to-reuse-rendered-component-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy-64628e1ca3eb read this article hope this will help you

Comment: You received a downvote probably `cause your question is a bit vague and it looks like you haven't researched the question enough yourself - there is lots of information available all over the Internet. Web Storage is an umbrella term covering various caching options, of which Local Storage is one. Read about Web Storage to know your options. You may also simply store data in the working memory - this is how the RouteReuseStrategy works. The optimal choice for your particular case might be a simple memory cache, RouteReuse, Local Storage or even IndexedDB - hard to say without more context.

Comment: you can achieve this by different ways... if you do not reload the browser a service can do the trick, local storage is fine and ngRx is a good option too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about navigating away to another web page outside of your application, you cannot do this within Angular as any type of application state / state in memory is destroyed when the application is exited (ie: browser is closed or navigated away from).  One way to do it is using localstorage as you state or you can have some type of persisting the search history in a database.

Answer (score 0):

If by `when users shift to another page and they back` you mean that you just changed the Angular router back and forth so NGRX store may a good option to store your state and then you can retrieve it easily when going back to your desired screen. But if the browser is reloaded by changing the page then you must use local Storage because you need some persistence that is independent from angular context to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use route params in this case

When the user submits the search query,

- You need to **update those query params to the route** as well as network call
- So when the user came back from an external page by clicking the back button in the browser, then you can **use the route params to make the network call** and show the same result as earlier.